# Keeping tab fragment view unchanged

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a tabbed application using fragments. Following is a code snippet from one of the fragments in tabA

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    accountsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_accounts, viewGroup, false);

    //obtain the labels- Top 50 Spending aacounts
    spendingLabel = (TextView) accountsView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //get search box
    accountSearch = (EditText) accountsView.findViewById(R.id.vAccountSearch);

    return accountsView;
}
```

Here is the onStart()

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    fillData();
}
```

fillData() fetches dat from the server. The application now fills a listView on tab click (by calling fillData() ). If I switch to other tabs and come to tabA, the page again calls fillData() and recreates the whole view.

How do I stop it reloading and keep the view unchanged on tab switching?

Since I am a newbie into Fragments, I find it hard to find a solution. Has anyone dealt this before?

Comment: Why don't you call the fillData() in onCreateView. Any issues?

Comment: Yeah I can do that! But that does not make any change. It calls fillData() again

Answer (score 0):

According to the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png) of Android application try to override onCreate instead of onStart

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fillData();
}
```